# Splitting up string using regex with minimal amounts of delimeters

Tags: java, regex

I have run into a regex problem for the second time today that I cannot solve. This one I am not even sure can be solved with a regular expression. My input string is:

```
29 - Arizona Diamondbacks 15 - Atlanta Braves 1 - Baltimore Oriole 2 - Boston Red Sox 16 - Chicago Cubs 4 - Chicago White Sox
```

I need to split each of these up into an array in Java and I would like the output to return:

```
"29 - Arizona Diamondbacks" "15 - Atlanta Braves" "1 - Baltimore Oriole"...
```

each their own element in an array. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: At first I thought I could split on the "-" dash characters but then I realized that wasnt going to work because that was separating the numbers and the team names. So then I realized i was stuck there

Comment: Well, if you split on the dashes--specifically on `"\\s*\\-\\s*"`, the resulting array will be `{"29","Arizona Diamondbacks 15","Atlanta Braves 1",...}`. Can you piece together what you want from that array?

Comment: @JackManey: That's a bad idea.

Comment: @jlordo - Agreed, but it's a better start than asking to be spoon-fed...

Comment: @JackManey The String is simply too long to do that. It is a very large string. And I am not asking to be spoon fed anything..just asking for help

Comment: Well, in that case, you can always break off tokens via a `while` loop. Although, honestly, this task would be prettymuch trivial if you were to serialize your data via JSON or XML.

Comment: Lookaheads/behinds? `(?<= )(?=\d+ )` (_"split on a point in string which is preceded by a space, and followed by one or more digits followed by a space"_)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead:

```
String[] arr = str.split("\\s(?=\\d+ -)");
```

this will even work when there are numbers in the team names.

Comment: Thanks alot this was alot of help!!!

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match what you need:

```
(\d+ - \D+)( |$)
```

Group 1 of each match will have the values you want.